# What alternatives exist instead of freezer paper when it comes on shirt bleaching?

Tags: paper, material-selection

I have seen this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=140vNQ3pDVw) where you can customize tshirts with bleach. As a necessary part of it is freezer paper where you transfer stencil design on it. But in Greece is hard to come by, therefore I want to ask would an oven paper (locally known as `ladokola`) would be a good substitute, as the image shows bellow?

[image: Ladokola image found in duckduckgo]

Also I want to know if the `freezer paper` is the same as the `ladokola` (oven paper) as well. Also I want to know what alternatives I can use (eg. Bucher paper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done bleach  t-shirt designs using simple card stock paper.

After sketching a drawing on the card stock, I would cut out the design to form a stencil, and then I pinned the design in place to the shirt.

Make sure you also put something inside the shirt so the bleach doesn't go through to the other side (I've used cardboard for this since it gets ruined after the fact).

I've seen other people use some kind of tape -- is painter's tape easily accessible in Greece? You could also use the sticky pages of lint rollers since those are made to be able to stick  to but not damage clothing.

Comment: I assume you found card paper from old boxes

Comment: I used paper from an art class -- it was essentially the same material as organizing folders that go in a filing cabinet. In fact, you could even use those too. Just make sure the paper/material you use is (1) big enough to fit your design and (2) not too thin; if a paper type material is too thin, the bleach will saturate it and make your design look smudged.

Answer (score 8):

Freezer paper is a product that has a waxed coating on only one side. It's sort of like a hybrid of oven paper (also called parchment paper, baking paper, or ladokola) and wax paper.

Neither wax paper nor oven paper can substitute for freezer paper in this particular application, because the wax on one side is being used as a temporary adhesive. After heat is applied, the paper stencil stays in place firmly enough while the bleach solution is applied, but lightly enough that it can be peeled away when you're done.

So some possible alternatives -- which I admit I haven't tried, so they are all hypothetical:

- Oven paper (or butcher paper) will work to keep the bleach solution, but will *not* have the same adhesive property and the stencil might move out of position while you work.
- Use contact paper -- the video you link to doesn't recommend it because it will stick right away, not allowing for repositioning, but it *would* stay in place.
- Use a spray adhesive to stick your oven paper down. (Make sure you look for one that's relatively weak, you don't want the paper on the shirt forever.)
- Make a substitute for freezer paper [per this online tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wn0jg.jpg): a plastic bag ironed onto regular paper.
- I wouldn't use wax paper with an iron because the wax would get on your iron, but maybe you could use a layer of wax paper under a layer of oven paper, protecting the iron but still letting the stencil stick!

Comment: Would a garbage bag with some cheap paper do the job. I stick some paper (eg. oven paper) to a garbage bag and poke me desighn there

Comment: I'd experiment first -- the bag in the suggested tutorial was very thin plastic!

Comment: Also On spencil part if I stick a bunch of A4 Sheets a plain one and one with the stencil on top of oven paper, and cut through it with a X-ACTO knife I recon would do the job as well. (Also if I stick the paper solig to the table surface with duct tape as well)